# Syntax for Rails 6 SQL method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The following warning is appearing on certain controller actions.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): 
"CASE id WHEN 343[...]". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. 
This method should not be called with user-provided values, 
such as request parameters or model attributes.
```

But this method is not being called by "user-provided" values:

```
def find_ordered(ids)
  order_clause = "CASE id "
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    order_clause << "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index} "
  end
  order_clause << "ELSE #{ids.length} END"
  where(id: ids).order(order_clause)
end
```

it does invoke model attributes.  So how can this initializer method be syntaxed to be acceptable to Rails 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strictly 'user-provided value' but Rails cannot have any way to know whether a string comes from a user or is hard coded in the program.

The way to get around this is to use [`Arel.sql`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Arel.html#method-c-sql)

> Wrap a known-safe SQL string for passing to query methods, e.g.

```
where(id: ids).order(Arel.sql(order_clause))
```